# How to get the name of paired(Connected in mobile settings) bluetooth device?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I need to get the paired device Bluetooth device in xamarin forms. Please guide

```
var btInfo = blueToothManager.Name;
```

Here it shows only the mobile device name How can I obtained paired device name

Answer (score 0):

This will give you list of all paired devices

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
ar pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.BondedDevices;

List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (BluetoothDevice device in pairedDevices)
    list.Add(device.Name);
```

Note: This is android specific code and needs to be placed in Android project. You can use a simple dependency service to access it in your core project.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't want all paired device. I just want the connected device name

Comment: Are you looking for any specific type of device? Like headset?

Comment: I also use DefaultAdapter but to get the device name, this is now deprecated and I can't find many posts about the updated way to use BluetoothManager

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package [Plugin.BluetoothLE](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.BluetoothLE/) from nuget.

```
var devices = CrossBleAdapter.Current.GetConnectedDevices();
devices.Subscribe(deviceResult =>
{
    foreach (var device in deviceResult)
    {
        // do something
    }   
}
```

Don't forget add permission in iOS and Android project . For more details you can check https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle#setup